# NodeJS (JavaScript) - Fastest method to convert date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, date-formatting

In NodeJS, I'm reading and parsing a .txt file with more than 1.5M lines. Each line is in the format: `date,number,number`, where each date is `yyyyMMddhhmmss`. An example line is:

```
20170506014255,100.01,200.02
```

Using [jFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jfile), I can read and parse all 1.5M+ lines in about 2 seconds...

```
var jFile = require('jfile');

var data = [];

var dataFile = new jFile('./dataFile.txt');

dataFile.lines.forEach(function(line) {
    data.push(line.split(','));
});
```

Works great! But, I'd like to change the date format to something else. For this, I am using [date-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-format) to do the conversion...

```
... same as previous, with new line within forEach() ...

var dateFormatter = require('date-format');

dataFile.lines.forEach(function(line) {
    let tdata = line.split(',');
    tdata[0] = dateFormatter('MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss', dateFormatter.parse('yyyyMMddhhmmss', tdata[0]));
    data.push(tdata);
});
```

Again, this works great! Mostly. **What once took only 2 seconds now takes about 25 seconds.** Gasp!

Ideally, the file would just have the dates formatted the correct way, but this is out of my hands.

Is there a faster way to do this conversion? Maybe there is a more native approach, or just a faster package?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is faster to hardcode the parsing:

```
 function fixFormat(date) {
  const yy = date.slice(2, 4);
  const MM = date.slice(4, 6);
  const dd = date.slice(6, 8);
  const hh = date.slice(8, 10);
  const mm = date.slice(10, 12);
  const ss = date.slice(12, 14);

  return `${MM}/${dd}/${yy} ${hh}:${mm}:${ss}`;
 }
```

Or really really ugly:

```
const y = 2, M = 4, d = 6, h = 8, m = 10, s = 12;
const pattern = fn => date => fn(p => date[p] + date[p + 1])

const fixFormat = pattern(p => p(M) + "/" + p(d) + "/" + p(y) + " " + p(h) + ":" + p(m) + ":" + p(s));
```

Comment: Boom! Only adds one second of processing time, for the entire set. I'm confident that every date will be formatted identically, so this is ideal. Thanks a tonne! I'll still accept your answer, but you have `yyyy` up top and `yy` in the return. I just changed the first parse to `const yy = date.slice(2, 4);`, since I'm only interested in the last two characters anyway. Great fix though!

Comment: Might a single regex match be faster than 6 consecutive calls to .slice()? Would have to run some benchmarks. /[0-9]{2,2}([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})/

Comment: @EricVautier—yes, but the regular expression can be very much simpler if combined with *match*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to play a game of coding golf to see who can write the fastest code for you.

Anything that parses the string, creates a Date, then generates a string from if it going to be slower than something that just reformats the string. Jonas' approach is valid, and probably fast enough, but all those slices must take their toll. A single match should be faster, but it's up to you:

```js
// Convert a timestamp in yyyyMMddhhmmss format to MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss
// where "hh" is assumed to be 24 hr
function formatDate(s) {
  var b = s.match(/\d\d/g);
  return `${b[2]}/${b[3]}/${b[1]} ${b[4]}:${b[5]}:${b[6]}`;
}

console.log(formatDate('20170506014255'));
```

I have no idea if that's faster, but it's certainly a lot less code. If you really want to make it fast, create the regular expression once:

```js
// Convert a timestamp in yyyyMMddhhmmss format to MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss
// where "hh" is assumed to be 24 hr
var formatDate = (function() {
  var re = /\d\d/g;
  return function (s) {
    var b = s.match(re);
    return `${b[2]}/${b[3]}/${b[1]} ${b[4]}:${b[5]}:${b[6]}`;
  };
}());

console.log(formatDate('20170506014255'));
```

Comment: We just need a testcase to see who wins ... :)

Comment: @JonasWilms—[*https://jsperf.com/reformat-date*](https://jsperf.com/reformat-date). It identified MS Edge as Chrome 64. Seems string operations are highly optimised. Unless you're running Edge…

Comment: and I should definetly update my Firefox ... the next version seems to double the overall speed (or my cpu is just slow), however this seems like a clear win :)